# jQuery Validation plugin minLength for checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-validate

this is my first post here on stackoverflow and am very impressed by the site!

My question is about the jQuery Validation plugin...specifically about the `minlength` method.
I have a group of checkboxes and I want to know if at least 2 boxes were checked.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength#length

at this link there is documentation about the `minlength` method being used with a regular input box, but not a checkbox. Can anyone help me on how to use if for checkboxes?

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this.  When all checkboxes in group share same `name`, the `minlength` method will ensure at least that number of checkboxes are selected.  http://jsfiddle.net/gmvck6oe/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a default method. Fortunately you can add it.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('has2selected',function(value, element) {
return $(element).filter(':checked').length >= 2;
}, 'the error message');
```

EDIT: I read again the documentation and the minlength should work (if wasn't the case the above code can make the job). You didn't post the code so I'm not sure if this is causing the error, but in your post is **minLength** it has to be **minlength**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the jQuery validation plugin, but I imagine you could do something like:

```
if($('.myCheckBoxes :checked').length > 2) {
   alert('at least two have been checked');
}
```

assuming your checkboxes have a class of **myCheckBoxes**

or something like:

```
if($("input[type='checkbox'] :checked").length > 2) {
   alert('at least two have been checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't usable for checkboxes.  The concept of 'length' it refers to is string length.  You would need to make a [custom validation method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) to get the behavior you want, or possibly do something fancy with [dependency expressions in `required`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression).

karim79's answer is a start on what you'd need to put in a custom validation method.  (The condition, not the alert.)

Comment: @ the link i posted in my post it states..."Works with text inputs, selects and checkboxes."